# number_in_month exercise (SML error unbound variable)

Tags: sml

I am trying to learn SML, and I am trying to implement two functions. The first function works fine, but when I added the second function it gives me an run-time error:

```
stdIn:1.2-1.17 Error: unbound variable or constructor: number_in_month
```

This happens while calling the function number_in_month. My code is:

```
 fun is_older(d1 :int*int*int,d2 :int*int*int) =
  (#1 d1) < (#1 d2) andalso (#2 d1) < (#2 d2) andalso (#3 d1) < (#3 d2)


fun number_in_month(da :(int * int * int) list ,mo : int) =
    if da = []
    then 0
    else if (#2(hd da)) = mo
     then 1 + number_in_month((tl da),mo)
    else 0 + number_in_month((tl da),mo)
```

Comment: Are you sure the error you get points to this code? Also, unbound variables are certainly no runtime errors in SML.

Comment: Code works fine. That error means that the function is not defined. Maybe you just forgot to reload your file.

Answer (score 1):

Your question sounds surprisingly much like these other questions: [SML list iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470895/sml-list-iteration) (8 months ago), [recursion in SML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409502/recursion-in-sml) (9 months ago), and [Count elements in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429734/count-elements-in-a-list) (8 months ago), so you certainly don't get points for asking a creative question.

Some of the questions above have been answered **extensively**. Look at them.

Here is your code rewritten in a better style:

```
(* Find better variable names than x, y and z. *)
fun is_older ((x1,y1,z1), (x2,y2,z2)) =
    x1 < x2 andalso y1 < y2 andalso z1 < z2

fun number_in_month ([], mo) = 0
  | number_in_month ((x,y,z)::rest, mo) =
    if y = mo then 1 + number_in_month(rest, mo)
              else 0 + number_in_month(rest, mo)
```

Comment: Or even better: `(if y = mo then 1 else 0) + number_in_month(rest, mo)` :)

Comment: Or even better: `fun number_in_month (dates, mo) = foldl (fn ((_,mo',_), n) => (if mo = mo' then 1 else 0) + n) 0 dates`